# Risk (Strategy Game) winning probabilities and expected troops lost

Tags: probability, markov-chain-montecarlo

Recently, I was introduced to the European version of Risk, the strategy game, which is almost the same as the USA version, but with a slight variation in the attacking method. First of all, the attacker and the defender both have $3$ dice. The players may only attack or defend with a maximum number of $3$ troops (even if more are available), and the attacker must have more than $1$ troop to attack. The player may attack a bordering country multiple times in the same turn. As an example, suppose I have $15$ troops in Ontario and my opponent has $4$ troops in Alberta. Since I have more than $3$ troops, I am allowed to throw $3$ dice (if I had $2$ troops instead of $15$ I would only be allowed to throw $2$ dice), same goes for my opponent. The outcome is $(6,5,3)$ vs $(2,6,6)$. In this case, we must pair the biggest number on my dice with the biggest number of my opponent's dice, and so on. In other words $$\begin{aligned}
&\text{My outcome}\qquad &\text{Opponent Outcome}\\ 
&(\color{red}{6},\color{blue}{5},\color{green}{3}) &(\color{green}{2},\color{blue}{6},\color{red}{6})
\end{aligned}$$

where the colors denote the pairing. For each pairing, the attacker must have a bigger number to destroy his opponent's troop. For the example above, $6$ is not greater than $6$ so the attacker loses one troop, $6$ is greater than $5$ so the attacker loses another troop, and $3$ is greater than $2$ so the defender loses one troop. In this round, I lost $2$ troops and my adversary only $1$. Therefore, my current troops in Ontario are $13$ and my opponent's troops in Alberta are $3$. I may decide to end the turn here or keep on attacking until I either destroy all of my opponent's troops or I am left with $1$ troop (so that I cannot attack anymore).

I was particularly interested in calculating the probability, given the number of attackers and defenders, of successfully conquering a bordering country (meaning that I keep on attacking the same country until I destroy all of my oponent's troops or I am left with one). The case with arbitrary attackers and $1$ defender is quite trivial, and the closed form formula $p(a,d)$ is
$$p(a,1)=1-\frac{1}{6^{a-1}}\prod_{j=1}^{a-1}\sum_{i=1}^6\left(\frac i6\right)^{j+1}, \quad a\in\mathbb{N}^*$$
with $a$ denoting the number of attackers and $d$ the number of defenders.
I wrote a quick C++ Monte Carlo simulation to check the validity of my work, and in fact, it does hold.

However, I was much more interested in generalizing this result for arbitrary $d$. Supplementing this result with the expected number of troops lost in the conquer (this would need another pair of hands and some work), may lead to much more efficient play. In fact, a player, given this information, may find what the minimal optimal number of troops is needed to conquer a territory given a specified probability and a specified tolerance for number of troops lost.

Of course simulations may be used in determining the probabilities and expected values, but an analytic solution would be, mathematically speaking, a better option to have (and would answer the optimization problem instantly).

I researched some papers on the topic at hand, but the few that are available use Monte Carlo Chains and do not give a closed form formula for what I am seeking, like the one I have provided. Furthermore, they are not related to the slight variation of the gameplay I mentioned in the beginning.

I have tried approaching the problem by cases, as I did with $d=1$. Although it seems very possible, the work is enormous. This because it reduces to a recursion equation depending on a couple of different functions. A closed form for the latter, is either above my skill level, or will take **a lot** of work.

I am interested in suggestions, ideas or even references to tackle the second part of my problem (i.e. finding a closed-form formula for arbitrary $a$ and $d$).
If anyone is interested in the simulation code or the work for the $a$ arbitrary and $d=1$, I will be more than happy to share it.

Comment: Is it a rule that if the defender has only 1 troop, then no matter hw many troops the attacker has, the attacker can only use 1 troop (i.e. roll one die)? Does your solution for $p(a,1)$ assume the attacker always uses 1 die? Also, can either the attacker or defender choose any number of dice (either 1, 2, or 3) if they have 3 or more troops?

Comment: @JohnL Yes that is a rule, and therefore my solution takes that into consideration. And for the last question, you do not choose, if you have more than three troops (or exactly three) you have to use $3$ dice, if you have two troops you have to use $2$ dice.

Comment: The defender has to use 3 if they have 3 or more and has to use 2 if they have two troops. So does the attacker, but the attacker is not allowed to use more than the defender?

Comment: @JohnL Suppose the attacker has $3$ troops and the defender has $2$. The attacker will use $3$ dice and the defender $2$. Furthermore, suppose the attacker has $20$ troops and defender $10$. In this case, the attacker must use $3$ troops and so the defender. Lastly, suppose the attacker has $1$ troop and the defender $40$. The attacker may not attack the defender because only one troop is available for the attack ($2$ or more must be available to attack a bordering country). I hope these examples are exhaustive and clear.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_{i_1,j_1,i_2,j_2}$ denote the probability of a certain outcome in a single roll (or, what I will call a mini-battle)
-the attacker rolls $i_1$ dice
-the defender rolls $j_1$ dice
-a roll means both players roll all of their dice
-$i_2$ is the number of troops the attacker loses
-$j_2$ is the number of troops the defender loses

For example,
$a_{2,1,1,0}=$ the probability that the attacker loses one troop
and the defender loses 0 troops when the attacker rolls two dice and defender rolls 1 die $=\frac{1}6\left(\frac{1^2}6+\frac{2^2}{6^2}+\frac{3^2}{6^2}+\frac{4^2}{6^2}+\frac{5^2}{6^2}+\frac{6^2}{6^2} \right)=\frac{91}{216}$

Important cases:
$a_{3,3,0,3}=$ the probability that the attacker loses zero troops
and the defender loses three troops when both players roll three dice $=\frac{6420}{6^6}$
$a_{3,3,1,2}=\frac{10017}{6^6}$
$a_{3,3,2,1}=\frac{12348}{6^6}$
$a_{3,3,3,0}=\frac{17871}{6^6}$

The average number of troops lost by the attacker in a 3 vs 3 mini-battle (one roll of the dice) is $\frac{88326}{6^6} \approx 1.893$. Thus, the defender on average loses 1.107 troops. The attacker should start with $\frac{1.893}{1.107} \approx 1.71$ times more troops to have the long term advantage in the battle. Roughly, if the attacker has 70% more troops than the defender, they will have more than 50% chance of winning. Otherwise they have less than 50% chance of winning.

Another important case:
$a_{3,1,1,0}=\frac{49}{144}$

Thus,
for $j\ge 1$ we have $p(1,j)=0$ because the attacker is not allowed to attack.
$p(2,1)=1-P[\text{attacker loses the mini-battle}]=1-a_{2,1,1,0}$
and for $n>2$, we have $p(n,1)=1-P[\text{attacker loses all mini-battles}]=1-a_{2,1,1,0} (a_{3,1,1,0})^{n-2}$

Define the generating function $$f(x,y)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty p(i,j) x^i y^j$$
where $p(i,j)$ is the probability that the attacker wins the battle when they start with $i$ troops and the defender starts with $j$ troops.
Make the conventions  and .

We have the following:
$$p(0,j)=p(1,j)=0$$
$$p(i,0)=1 \text{ if } i>1$$

$$p(2,1)=a_{2,1,0,1}$$
$$p(2,2)= a_{2,2,0,2}$$
If $i,j\ge 3$ then $$p(i,j)=\sum_{i_2=0}^3 a_{3,3,i_2,3-i_2}p(i-i_2,j-3+i_2)$$
If $i\ge 3$ then $$p(i,2)=\sum_{i_2=0}^2 a_{3,2,i_2,2-i_2}p(i-i_2,i_2)$$
If $i\ge 3$ then $$p(i,1)=\sum_{i_2=0}^1 a_{3,1,i_2,1-i_2}p(i-i_2,i_2)$$
If $j\ge 3$ then $$p(2,j)=a_{2,3,0,2}p(2,j-2)$$

Note that
$$f(x,y)-\sum_{j=0}^\infty p(2,j) x^2 y^j
-\sum_{i=3}^\infty p(i,0) x^i y^0$$
$$-\sum_{i=3}^\infty p(i,1) x^i y^1-\sum_{i=3}^\infty p(i,2) x^i y^2$$
$$=\sum_{i=3}^\infty\sum_{j=3}^\infty p(i,j) x^i y^j$$
$$=\sum_{i=3}^\infty\sum_{j=3}^\infty \sum_{i_2=0}^3 a_{3,3,i_2,3-i_2}p(i-i_2,j-3+i_2) x^i y^j$$
$$=\sum_{i=3}^\infty\sum_{j=3}^\infty  a_{3,3,0,3}p(i,j-3) x^i y^j+\sum_{i=3}^\infty\sum_{j=3}^\infty  a_{3,3,1,2}p(i-1,j-2) x^i y^j$$
$$+\sum_{i=3}^\infty\sum_{j=3}^\infty  a_{3,3,2,1}p(i-2,j-1) x^i y^j+\sum_{i=3}^\infty\sum_{j=3}^\infty  a_{3,3,3,0}p(i-3,j) x^i y^j$$

$$=a_{3,3,0,3}y^3\sum_{i=3}^\infty\sum_{j=3}^\infty  p(i,j-3) x^i y^{j-3}
+a_{3,3,1,2}x y^2\sum_{i=3}^\infty\sum_{j=3}^\infty  p(i-1,j-2) x^{i-1} y^{j-2}$$
$$+a_{3,3,2,1}x^2 y\sum_{i=3}^\infty\sum_{j=3}^\infty  p(i-2,j-1) x^{i-2} y^{j-1}
+a_{3,3,3,0} x^3\sum_{i=3}^\infty\sum_{j=3}^\infty  p(i-3,j) x^{i-3} y^j$$

$$=a_{3,3,0,3}y^3\sum_{i=3}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty  p(i,j) x^i y^j
+a_{3,3,1,2}x y^2\sum_{i=2}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty  p(i,j) x^i y^j$$
$$+a_{3,3,2,1}x^2 y\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=2}^\infty  p(i,j) x^i y^j
+a_{3,3,3,0} x^3\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=3}^\infty  p(i,j) x^i y^j$$

$$=a_{3,3,0,3}y^3\left(f(x,y)-\sum_{j=0}^\infty  p(2,j) x^2 y^j\right)$$
$$+a_{3,3,1,2}x y^2\left(f(x,y)-\sum_{i=2}^\infty  p(i,0) x^i y^0 \right)  $$
$$+a_{3,3,2,1}x^2 y \left( f(x,y)- \sum_{i=1}^\infty  p(i,1) x^i y^1- \sum_{i=1}^\infty  p(i,0) x^i y^0\right)$$
$$+a_{3,3,3,0} x^3 \left(f(x,y)-\sum_{i=0}^\infty  p(i,0) x^i y^0-\sum_{i=0}^\infty  p(i,1) x^i y^1-\sum_{i=0}^\infty  p(i,2) x^i y^2 \right)$$

Now, solve for $f(x,y)$. You can take the derivatives of different orders of $f(x,y)$ wrt $x$ and $y$ and plug in $x=0,y=0$ to find the probabilities $p(a,d)$.

Some of the steps needed to solve:
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty  p(i,0) x^i=\frac{x}{1-x}$$

$$\sum_{i=2}^\infty  p(i,1) x^i$$
$$=a_{2,1,0,1} x^2 + 
\sum_{i=3}^\infty  (1-a_{2,1,1,0} (a_{3,1,1,0})^{i-2}) x^i$$
$$=x^2\left(a_{2,1,0,1}+\frac{x(1+a_{2,1,1,0}a_{3,1,1,0}(x-1)-a_{3,1,1,0}x)}
{(x-1)(a_{3,1,1,0}x-1)}\right)$$

$$\sum_{i=3}^\infty  p(i,2) x^i
=\sum_{i=3}^\infty  \left( \sum_{i_2=0}^2 a_{3,2,i_2,2-i_2}p(i-i_2,i_2) \right) x^i$$
$$=\sum_{i=3}^\infty  a_{3,2,i_2,2}p(i,0) x^i+\sum_{i=3}^\infty  a_{3,2,1,1}p(i-1,1) x^i+\sum_{i=3}^\infty  a_{3,2,2,0}p(i-2,2) x^i$$
$$=a_{3,2,i_2,2} \frac{x^3}{1-x}
+a_{3,2,1,1}x\sum_{i=2}^\infty p(i,1) x^i
+a_{3,2,2,0} x^2\sum_{i=1}^\infty p(i,2) x^i$$
Then, this equation can be solved for $\sum_{i=3}^\infty  p(i,2) x^i$.

Solving for the generating function $f(x,y)$ is not easy, but it can be done, I think.